# Using VB to alter row colour in Excel if checkbox on same row is ticked

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have an Excel spreadsheet listing various courses. I have checkboxes in column F for each course (not for every row - there are some gaps). When a checkbox is ticked I want to alter the color of cells B to E on the same row.

Would there be a way of doing this in one method rather than copying the code for each checkbox?

Any help appreciated as always - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox idea will be hard to implement. But if you want to have a clickable way to set the background of the cells in that row you can insert a hyperlink on  your course title. Have the hyperlink point to the adjacent cells in that row. So if the title is on B3, have the hyperlink point to C3:E3, for example.

Implement the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink event on your sheet's code-behind. Here is a sample sub to get you started:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range(Application.Selection.Address)
    myRange.Interior.Color = RGB(127, 256, 256)
End Sub
```

This works on Excel 2007. Untested on other versions.

Comment: Thanks for the great alternative approach Andrew!!

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same macro to all the checkboxes. The issue you may have is trying to figure out what row the checkbox sits on. The controls don't actually sit in the grid. They sit on top of the worksheet and have no reference to the rows.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Excel VB noob here. Is it possible to reference a row in the spreadsheet in VB? Perhaps a method that takes the row reference as an argument?

Comment: Apologies that's probably a terrible approach the more I think about it. Think I'll just give up!

Comment: If you need that each checkbox was going to represent a certain row you could assign each its own macro and then pass the row location from that macro to a common function/sub. Kinda round about but welcome to Excel programming ;)